# Exim sync emails from AWS SES

Tags: imap, amazon-ses, dovecot, exim

I would like to build a new email server.
I am familiar with Exim+Dovecot solution. But it's a bit complicated to set up.
So I would like to try AWS SES because it's much simpler to start and has nice integration with mainstream mail servers.

The problem I am having is how do I recieve emails. It seems SES will put all the received mails in a S3 bucket. But I want to receive mails on my phone, ipad, laptop, so I still need an imap server. Is it possible to have a script to sync the s3 bucket to my exim server so that exim can forward the email to dovecot?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @amt I've now completely got rid of exim and using aws only. Now I just need a way to sync mails from s3 bucket to an imap server so that I can receive mails from my phone. I've tried adding a SNS topic to trigger a lambda function to forward to my gmail, but SNS has a limit of 150k.